# Appender for IISLog (HttpResponse)?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, log4net, httpresponse, iis-logs

Inside an MVC - application I need to write into the IIS-Log. I do this by calling "AppendToLog()" from the HttpResponse:

```
public static void IIsLog(this HttpResponseBase response, string message, params object [] parameters)
        {
            if (response == null) return;
            response.AppendToLog(string.Format(message, parameters));
        }
```

Now I usually use log4net to log into logfiles instead, so it would be perfect to use an appender that does exactly the same like my custom code above.

I wasn't able to find any appender [on the Apache-Documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/log4net-1.2.13/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.html) that fits my needs.

Is there any appender that fits my needs?

Comment: You can simply create your own log appender by deriving from `AppenderSkeleton` and overriding `Append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)`. Also to get access to the current response object, you can use `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response`. Make sure `Currnet` and `Response` are not null before trying to `Write`.